# Handling Date Transformation in Component in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript, date-pipe

I am trying to transform the way some dates are displayed in my Angular 2 app. In my case, using the date pipe in the view along with string interpolation is not an option, because my template code looks like this:

```
<input class="app-input"
    [(ngModel)]="staff.profile.hireDate" placeholder="None"
    [field-status]="getPropertyStatus('profile.hireDate')"/>
```

A commenter suggested I try handling the transformation of the date in the component, before passing it to the view. This is what he wrote:

> You can do this in your component.
>
> import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'; then either add it to the
>   providers array in component or in your ngModule.
>
> In your component you inject this in your constructor:
>
> constructor(private myDatePipe: DatePipe) {} and modify your variable
>   property:
>
> this.staff.profile.hireDate = 
>       this.myDatePipe.transform(new Date(this.staff.profile.hireDate));

This sounds like the perfect solution. However, I'm still unclear on the exact implementation. I have imported `DatePipe` and have defined a local instance in the constructor. But where does this next part go:

`this.staff.profile.hireDate = this.myDatePipe.transform(new Date(this.staff.profile.hireDate));`

I tried putting it in the body of the constructor, but no go.

So I'm still a little unclear as to where this goes, and if I need to also change the code in the view after that.

Any clarity would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use DatePipe that way

```
NgModule({
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
```

and inside your component:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
...
this.staff.profile.hireDate= this.datePipe.transform(this.staff.profile.hireDate, 'dd-MM-yy');
```

Comment: And then what would I put in the actual template? As is as you have it, you'll get an error. Did you mean to put "this.myDate" within the body of the constructor?

Comment: You still have this.staff.profile.hireDate sitting outside of the body of the constructor. This will cause an error.